# I am the domain admin, newbie, how do I connect youtube.com on my domain?

Tags: asp.net, dns, youtube, google-admin-sdk, google-domain-api

See title start forward... I need to log onto youtube as I am a new domain admin many thanks in advance!

research google domain admin
allowed sites
no workie

How can I access, log in, create a youtube account for my new business? Im having trouble getting myself access while being a new online business owner.

YELP! :)))